# Check if a reuleaux triangle is inside/outside a triangle/pentagon/circle in C

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

You could check for Definition for Reuleaux Triangles here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_triangle

I had been dealing with geometric 2D shapes and doing checks, set up tests to see if they intersects another, or is inside another shape(touching included). I had tested circles (defined with a **Point** type as the center with *double* x,y properties as coordinates, along with a *double* radius), triangles (with three vertices **Point**), pentagons (with five vertices **Point**) so far, but I found an interesting shape that's called reuleaux triangle, which is formed by three circles, and the arc edge has the same distance to the vertex on the opposite side.

First I tried to see if the vertices is inside the shape as if I use the edge as a part of the original big circle which the vertex across is the center, or try that if part of other shapes I mentions above intersects it (the circle is more confusing than shapes with straight edges), but I stuck as I don't know how to restrict the angle or something so I could scan only this part of the arc is to be tested, and it's actually hard to setup a test to get the intersect detected.

I tried to find the distance from the vertex to the midpoint of the are edge, and see it as a hexagon, but there is always more space in the small arc sections that would not be included. Now I have no idea about setting up a new method to test if this weird round triangle would be inside/outside/intersects/touching any of the shapes (Circle, Triangle, Pentagon) that I already found a way to measure the positional relations.

So what's your idea about this? Maybe the three big circles that forms this triangle would help?

Comment: You can use the angle between center of mass of your goofy triangle and another object to restrict your search to the two quadrants of your object that lie to either side of that vector. Is there a simple algorithm you can use to identify each of the edge coordinates of your special triangle? You could test whether those penetrate your other object(s).

Comment: I would start with a binary search along the edge starting at the intersection of the line between the centers of the two objects, then check progressively further away on either side. I am sure there's some optimizations that can be applied with regard to polyhedral's that approximate each of your curves.

Comment: @jwdonahue Thanks for the reminder. I will try to use my tags wisely next time. I think the hardest part is to figure out how to determine it in geometric approach, then it's easy for me to implement it in code. The code is not my main problem so sorry for confusion:) Now I am almost there, but still thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Find the intersection points of the other shape with the circle around corner A of the Reuleaux triangle, and also the vertices of the other shape which lie inside the circle around A (together these are the 4 black points in the image below).

Then check whether any of these points lie to the right of line AB and to the left of line AC (i.e. the red sector in the image; 2 of the 4 black points do, so the shapes intersect).

[image: Reuleaux Triangle and Pentagon]

Do the same for the circles around B and C. This will give you all the intersection points of the Reuleaux triangle and the other shape, and all the vertices of the other shape that are inside the Reuleaux triangle.

Additionally you should check whether the corners A, B and C lie inside the other shape, in case the whole Reuleaux triangle is inside the other shape.

It should be possible to do this by combining (parts of) functions you already have for circles and triangles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general method to handle all curvilinear convex polygons, using the sweepline approach.

First find all event points, i.e. the endpoints of the arcs and segments, plus the horizontal tangency points, and sort them by ordinate to split the plane in "slabs".

[image]

The slabs defines "curvilinear trapezoids", delimited by two horizontal sides (possibly degenerated) and two monotonous arcs or segments.

[image]

If the horizontal sides do overlap, you can be sure that the two shapes overlap. But even if they don't, an overlap is still possible in between. For this, you need to detect intersections of the sides. The intersection formulas for two circles and/or segments are not too difficult. If you find intersections, you need to check if they belong to the current slab by a test on the ordinates.

[image]